# convert binary search tree to lists

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I tried to debug this question: converting a binary search tree to linked lists of all nodes at each level. But I encountered run time error.  In the code, I basically run BFS of the binary search tree and keep track of each level, if a new level hit, I create a new linked list to store the new level's node. I used the STL's linked list to store the nodes. Before that I create a binary search tree using function min_height. I test these methods with input vector={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. The tree looks like the following picture. It runs well for some nodes, but stop at node 2. I cannot figure out the reason, could someone help me with it? Thank you ![image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

template<typename Key, typename Value>
struct BSTNode{
 Key key;
 Value value;
 BSTNode * left;
 BSTNode * right;
 BSTNode(Key k, Value v, BSTNode *l=NULL, BSTNode *r=NULL): key(k), value(v), left(l), right(r) {}
 };


template<typename Key, typename Value>
vector< list<BSTNode<Key, Value>*> > creat_lists(BSTNode<Key, Value>* root){
 vector< list<BSTNode<Key, Value>*> > v;
 if(root==NULL) return v; 
 queue<BSTNode<Key, Value>*> q;   queue<int> level;  int prev;
 q.push(root);   level.push(0);   prev=-1;
 while(!q.empty()){
  BSTNode<Key, Value>* cur=q.front();    int cur_level=level.front();
  cout<<"cur->key: "<<cur->key<<" cur_level: "<<cur_level<<endl;

  if(prev!=cur_level){
    list<BSTNode<Key, Value>*> l;
    l.push_back(cur);
    v.push_back(l);
  }
  else  {cout<<"got in"<<endl;  v.back().push_back(cur);}

  if(cur->left )cout<<"cur->left: "<<cur->left->key<<endl;
  if(cur->right )cout<<"cur->right: "<<cur->right->key<<endl;

  prev=cur_level;
  if(cur->left) {q.push(cur->left);  level.push(cur_level+1); }
  if(cur->right) {q.push(cur->right);  level.push(cur_level+1);}



  q.pop();    level.pop();


 }
return v;
}


template<typename Key, typename Value>
BSTNode<Key, Value>* min_height(vector<int> &v, int left, int right ){// here is different from my paper code
  if(left<=right){
    int mid=left+ (right-left)/2;
    BSTNode<Key, Value>* node=new BSTNode<Key, Value>(v[mid], v[mid]);
    node->left=min_height<Key, Value>(v, left, mid-1 );
    node->right=min_height<Key, Value>(v, mid+1, right );
    return node;
    }
}


int main(){
  vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);
  v.push_back(4);
  v.push_back(5);
  v.push_back(6);  
  BSTNode<int, int>* root=min_height<int, int>(v, 0, 5);
 vector<list<BSTNode<int, int>*> > newv=creat_lists(root);
 //for(int i=0; i<newv.size(); i++)  cout<<(v[i].front())->key<<endl;
}



complier result:
Run Status: Runtime Error

cur->key: 3 cur_level: 0
cur->left: 1
cur->right: 5
cur->key: 1 cur_level: 1
cur->right: 2
cur->key: 5 cur_level: 1
got in
cur->left: 4
cur->right: 6
cur->key: 2 cur_level: 2
```

Comment: I can't be certain (since I can't reproduce the error) but I think you're getting undefined behavior, because you have dangling pointers in your tree, because your `min_height(...)` doesn't always return anything. What compiler are you using, that doesn't warn you of this?

Comment: I would like to know what do you mean by dangling pointer? I tried different complier, but none of them give me enough usful information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a stab in the dark.

A **dangling pointer** is a pointer that points to a location in memory that is *not* the address of a legitimate object of the expected type. It might be the address of a defunct object no longer under the protection of the memory manager, or a location in the middle of some unrelated object, or a spot in unallocated memory, or even outside the bounds of real memory. In practice it can contain any old random junk, and trying to dereference it (i.e. use it as if it were a legitimate object) causes **undefined behavior** (i.e. anything can happen, and it can fail in peculiar ways).

A function should return a value of the type indicated by its signature. Your function `BSTNode<Key, Value>* min_height(...)` should return a pointer to a `BSTNode`. But as written it does so only `if(left<=right)`, otherwise it simply terminates; I'm not sure exactly what happens in this case, but I think it's possible that at least under some compilers it will return an undefined pointer-- random, and not in a good way. A good compiler will warn you about this. (In my opinion a good pointer should refuse to compile it, but that's another rant.)

So fix the function; have `min_height(...)` return the correct specific value if the conditional is not satisfied. If that doesn't fix the bug, let us know and we'll try something else. (**SPOILER:** ןןnu sı ǝnןɐʌ ɔıɟıɔǝds ʇɔǝɹɹoɔ ǝɥʇ.)

Comment: It works now, Thank you very much. I have an additonal question. Can a vector be NULL?

Comment: @dianedan: No, but it can be empty (that is, contain no elements). You can test for that condition with the member function `empty()`.

Comment: @dianedan: A *null pointer* is one whose value is zero. That value indicates that the pointer doesn't point to anything. There is a macro, `NULL` that evaluates to zero and can be cast to a pointer of any type. So you can set a pointer to it (`Node *ptr = NULL;`) or test a pointer (`if(ptr){...}`). You *could* set and compare pointers using other flavors of zero, like `int n=0;` or `bool b=false;`, but you really shouldn't.